# How to get steam icons in the Ubuntu dash? Specifically numix

Tags: 14.04, icons, steam, numix

I installed the numix icon pack and noticed the really nice steam game icons (Seen here: http://me4oslav.deviantart.com/art/Numix-Circle-Linux-Desktop-Icon-Theme-414741466). How can I get icons for my steam games in the dash? When I click create desktop shortcut in the game properties it just makes an icon on my actual desktop, kinda lame. Or are the icons for these desktop icons? Thanks for any help, sorry for a confusing question. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You may be able to drag and drop the desktop icons to the dash.

Answer (score 1):

If you have activated the PPA and installed the package `numix-icon-theme-circle` via

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme-circle
```

then the icon theme is already installed in your system. Enable the icon theme if not already done so.

---

- You can find the icons in the folder

  ```
  /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle
  ```
- You could check the installed files/icons with the command

  ```
  dpkg -L numix-icon-theme-circle
  ```
- Search a concrete icon with, E.G.

  ```
  find /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle -iname '*minecraft*'
  ```

  or

  ```
  dpkg -L numix-icon-theme-circle | grep -i minecraft
  ```

---

- To use an icon, you need to edit the corresponding desktop file for the game / program. Because the files are located on your desktop, open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and edit the file with your preferred editor, EG

  ```
  gedit ~/Desktop/minecraft.desktop
  ```

  or

  ```
  nano ~/Desktop/minecraft.desktop
  ```
- Find the line that starts with

  ```
  Icon=some_icon
  ```

  and replace it with, EG

  ```
  Icon=minecraft
  ```

  without any extension and/or path.

That's all.